Excel export: extra row added above headers and missing second column from DataGridView in VB.NET
I'm working on exporting data from a DataGridView to an Excel sheet using VB.NET. However, I'm facing two issues:

An extra row is being inserted above the headers in Excel
The second column from my DataGridView is not showing up in Excel.

Here's the code I'm using:
' Starting row and column for the data
Dim startRow As Integer = 66
Dim startColumn As Integer = 3  ' Column C corresponds to the 3rd column in Excel

    ' Assign headers in row 66
    For j = 0 To DailyReportBackend.DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        oSheet.Cells(startRow, startColumn + j) = DailyReportBackend.DataGridView1.Columns(j).HeaderText
    Next
    
    ' Assign data starting directly from row 67
    For i = 0 To DailyReportBackend.DataGridView1.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To DailyReportBackend.DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            oSheet.Cells(startRow + i + 1, startColumn + j) = DailyReportBackend.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value?.ToString()
        Next
    Next

Issues

Extra row above headers: even though I intend for the headers to be placed in row 66, an additional blank row appears above the headers in Excel.

Missing second column: the first column from my DataGridView exports correctly, but the second column does not show up at all in Excel.


Here is what my datagridview looks like; I used this MySQL syntax to display this data in the datagridview
MY DATAGRIDVIEW EXAMPLE

MySQL code:
    SELECT 
        userinfo.status, COUNT(userinfo.status) as TOTAL, 
        userinfo.GradeLevelOrYearLvel,           
        userinfo.userinfo_natureofworkORSchool, 
        Login_info_Open, Login_info_closed, blhfeedback.Purpose 
    FROM 
        userinfo  
    LEFT JOIN 
        blhfeedback ON userinfo.userinfo_id = blhfeedback.id_of_studentinfo                        
    WHERE
        date(Login_info_Open) = date(date_sub(now(), interval 0 day))   
        AND LearningHub_LogIn = 'Tuyo'  
    GROUP BY 
        userinfo.status  
    ORDER BY     
        userinfo.GradeLevelOrYearLvel ASC

I've tried different variations of the code, but I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Is there something wrong with how I'm iterating over the DataGridView or assigning values to Excel cells?
How can I fix these issues? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
